# How do I achieve a gold score on the dribble drill?

Tags: nba2k12

Even though I made it past all the cones, blockers, and scored the shot(dunks and layups most of the time) on the dribble course drill (all three drills), my final score wasn't high enough to get a gold score.  What else do I need to do to get the gold score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beating the defenders on the second and third drills yields extra 150 points each time, there's also a time bonus relative to the time left on the clock. Check out this guide: